Why does POWERSHELL interpret my array of arrays like this?
I had a bug in my script that took me awhile to find.
I had an unintended comma at the beginning of the outer array.
Which caused the first element in the array to be treated in a way that I don't understand.
I thought it would treat the array has having 3 items, with the first being NULL.
If I remove the comma it works, if I put a null array @() before the comma it works.
I don't need to know how to make it work.
I'm just trying to understand why it's working as it does.
Here is the code that is failing and its results:
    $ALL = @(,
            @('A',@("B1","B2"),"C"),
            @('D',@("E1","E2"),"F")
            )
    $i=0
    foreach ($L in $ALL)
    {
        write-host "============== start i=$i ==========="
        $L
        write-host "=======l, count, [0]{1][2] ========="
        Write-host $L
        Write-host ($L.count)
        Write-host ($L[0])`t($L[1])`t($L[2])
        write-host "=============== end ================"
        $i++
    }

Output:
============== start i=0 ===========
A


Length         : 2
LongLength     : 2
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {B1, B2}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 2

C
=======l, count, [0]{1][2] =========
A B1 B2 C
1
A B1 B2 C        
=============== end ================
============== start i=1 ===========
D
E1
E2
F
=======l, count, [0]{1][2] =========
D E1 E2 F
3
D    E1 E2   F
=============== end ================

Here are the results when the extraneous comma is removed from the first line:
============== start i=0 ===========
A
B1
B2
C
=======l, count, [0]{1][2] =========
A B1 B2 C
3
A    B1 B2   C
=============== end ================
============== start i=1 ===========
D
E1
E2
F
=======l, count, [0]{1][2] =========
D E1 E2 F
3
D    E1 E2   F
=============== end ================

Any Thoughts as to how Powershell is interpreting the array when the first element is NULL?
The comma was a mistake that I overlooked.
When I noticed it, I thought Powershell would treat it as an empty element.

As the documentation states:

In expression mode, as a unary operator, the comma creates an array with just one member.

You're creating an array which's first element is another array (@('A', @('B1', 'B2'), 'C')).

To expand on @SantiagoSquarzon's answer, your first example is equivalent to this:
$ALL = @(
    (, @('A',@("B1","B2"),"C")),
    @('D',@("E1","E2"),"F")
)

where the leading comma is treated as an operator that acts on the A B1 B2 C array, which you can see if you convert the $All variable to json - in your original example and the one above you'll get:
$All | convertto-json -depth 99
[
  [
    [
      "A",
      [
        "B1",
        "B2"
      ],
      "C"
    ]
  ],
  [
    "D",
    [
      "E1",
      "E2"
    ],
    "F"
  ]
]

Note how the A B1 B2 C array is nested an extra level compared to the D E1 E2 F array - the leading , (Comma Operator) is being parsed in "expression mode" as a unary operator (similar to the syntactical structure of, say, -not $x).
It sounds like you were expecting it to parse as this instead:
$ALL = @(
    $null,
    @('A',@("B1","B2"),"C"),
    @('D',@("E1","E2"),"F")
)

which... it doesn't.
By comparison, without the leading comma you get this:
$ALL = @(
    @('A',@("B1","B2"),"C"),
    @('D',@("E1","E2"),"F")
)

$All | convertto-json -depth 99
[
  [
    "A",
    [
      "B1",
      "B2"
    ],
    "C"
  ],
  [
    "D",
    [
      "E1",
      "E2"
    ],
    "F"
  ]
]

where the A B1 B2 C array is at the same depth as the D E1 E2 F array, which is probably what you actually wanted in the first place...
